# For loop not a statement error

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm trying to use for loops to check if a user is inputting an integer. The code will not let the user pass unless it is given an integer. I'm going to post a portion of my code, but if you think the error is outside of what I posted, I'll post the rest:

error:

```
not a statement
```

Code:

```
for (int prompt = 1; prompt < mainarray.length; prompt++) {
    System.out.println("Please enter #" + prompt);
    checkint = scan.nextInt();

    // The error is pointing to the != in the following loop.

    //I have check int declared above this code.

    for (checkint != (int) checkint) {
        System.out.println("This is not an integer, please input an integer");
    }
    mainarray[prompt] = checkint;
    System.out.println("Number has been added\n");
}
```

Comment: Please review the syntax of a for loop.

Comment: `for(checkint != (int)checkint)` not a valid for loop.

Comment: Frankly I don't understand the comparison...

Comment: Isn't that an infinite loop?  (even if the syntax was valid)

Comment: You started this question with `For loop not a statement error` and then changed it so that you can input a number properly. Keep these as separate questions. Accept one of the answers that helped you with the `for loop statement error` and ask a new question about the input number exception problems you're having. You've changed your question completely.

Comment: Oh, I figured I shouldn't make a new one. Good to know.

Comment: I went ahead and did the rollback. As a general rule, *never* update a question to deal with a completely different issue, even if it arises from the same code. The *only* time you should ever be changing what the question asks is if the original formulation was off-topic, and even then, it shouldn't be a drastic change.

Comment: I'll make sure I do that, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an If statement to check this, not a `for loop`

```
if(checkint != (int)checkint)
{
    System.out.println("This is not an integer, please input an integer"); 
}
```

**Edit:**

The Op said he/she is getting error as: `java.util.InputMismatchException:null (in java.util.Scanner)`

**Solution:**

You are using `nextInt();`. The `java.util.Scanner.nextInt()` method Scans the next token of the input as an int. if the next token does not match the Integer regular expression, or is out of range it will throw `InputMismatchException`.

You can use this code

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = scan.nextLine();

try{
    val = Integer.parseInt(s);
}
catch(NumberFormatException ex){
    System.out.println("This is not an integer, please input an integer"); 
}
```

Even better,

```
try{
   checkint = scan.nextInt();
}
catch(Exception ex){
    System.out.println("This is not an integer, please input an integer"); 
}
```

**Edit2**

```
try
{
     checkint = scan.nextInt();
     mainarray[prompt]=checkint;
} 
catch(Exception ex)
{
     System.out.println("An integer is required;" + "input an integer please"); 
}
```

Comment: If I put it in characters, I get an error:
`java.util.InputMismatchException:null (in java.util.Scanner)`

Comment: @munchschair because you are using `scan.nextInt();` I''l update my answer

Comment: Wouldn't I have to convert the string to an int? I've never used try catch before, couldn't I just compare the String in the original if statement above?

Comment: @munchschair If you want to use if statement to compare, then don't use `scan.nextInt();`

Comment: Oh I see, this is made for exceptions. I'd still have to convert the string to an int, right?

Comment: What if I keep the if statement above, start off with a string, then convert the string to an int if it passes as an integer.

Comment: Alright, scratch what I just said. I input that code (where scan.nextInt(); and try catch are included), compiled and ran. If I put in letters, I still get a mismatch exception.

Comment: @munchschair See the difference in exception and try block.

Comment: No more exception errors, but if the user puts in non integers, the program goes ahead and says the number has been added, then goes onto the next integer but without asking for the input.

Comment: @munchschair Which means your condition false. change `for (int prompt = 1; prompt < mainarray.length; prompt++)` to for `(int prompt = 1; prompt < 10; prompt++)` and try

Comment: I need the array to be adjustable to user input. Making it less then 10 won't let the user set it's size. The code goes along to the rest of the loop. I want the try catch to keep the user inputting values until it is an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
for(checkint != (int)checkint)
```

as

```
for(;checkint != (int)checkint;)
```

From [Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

The general form of the for statement can be expressed as follows:

```
for (initialization; termination; increment) {
    statement(s)
}
```

- The *initialization* expression initializes the loop; it's executed
  once, as the loop begins.
- When the *termination* expression evaluates to false, the loop
  terminates.
- The *increment* expression is invoked after each iteration through the
  loop; it is perfectly acceptable for this expression to increment or
  decrement a value.

BUT this will leads to an infinite loop in your code. So change it as

```
if (checkint != (int)checkint)
```

Comment: I've never seen that before. So if you only have one statement inside, you have to cover it with semicolons?

Comment: @munchschair It has nothing to do with _covering it with semicolons_. A `for` loop has very specific syntax with 3 different expressions. Those expressions can be the empty statement.

Comment: So I'll have to use a different loop. I added the semi colons and got a `java.uil.inputmismatchexception: null` error.

Comment: A `for` takes three clauses. If you're providing only the conditional -- not the initialization or advance -- then you need the semicolons so the parser knows which clause you've provided. Of course if this was really what you wanted to write, you should instead have used `while`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(checkint != (int)checkint)
```

Isn't valid syntax for a for loop. That's a while loop. Consider this:

```
while (checkint != (int)checkint)
```

A while loop has one condition and will loop until that condition is not met. A for loop is actually just a while loop in disguise, but has three conditions:

`starting point/initialization; condition; increment`

However, you can leave the starting point and the increment blank to simulate a while loop.

---

**HOWEVER** this will put you in an ENDLESS LOOP. I don't know why you want a loop in the first place:

Finally, you should *actually* be doing this:

```
if (checkint != (int)checkint)
```